# Md5 cache keys in Memcache

Tags: caching, md5, memcached

In this [reddit blog post](http://blog.reddit.com/2010/03/and-fun-weekend-was-had-by-all.html), the author talks about MD5ing the cache keys and hence the reason why they find it very difficult to scale out.

Can someone tell me **why one would want to md5 cache keys?** I didn’t understand the reason even though they explained it as

> “A few years ago, we decided to md5
>   all of our cache keys. We did this
>   because at the time memcached (which
>   is what memcachedb is based on) could
>   only take keys of a certain length. In
>   fact, the version it is based on still
>   has this limitation. MD5ing the keys
>   was a good solution to this problem,
>   so we thought.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key size back then was probably shorter than it is now (currently 250 bytes - and 250 bytes is a pretty huge key name) meaning a sensible key naming convention may not have been possible, so they just used the sensible naming convention and md5'd it.

Answer (score 3):

> We did this because at the time memcached (which is what memcachedb is based on) could only take keys of a certain length

I guess that since some keys where larger than the max length the server allowed, they decided to create a md5 of the key to store it.

However, I'm not sure there is a relation between this and the fact that they can't easily add new servers (since memcached also use hashing to even repartition .. maybe memcachedb doesn't)